# Node.js [net library]: How to make the buffer object a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, client

I am fairly new to Node.js, and I am creating a TCP client that sends and receives data from a certain server.

My problem is with the `"data"` event emitted when data is received through the socket.

```
client.on('data', function(data) {    

    console.log('[TCP] Client received: ' + data); // Logs the message as it is supposed to be.

    console.log(data.split(" ")); // Does not work because it says that data is not a string
});
```

I tried `toString(data)` but it did not output it as it was logged by the console.

**So my question is:** How can I convert this object to a string as it is logged in the console?

*Thank you for your input :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `data` is a `Buffer` instance as it looks like, it's

```
client.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
})
```